# How to use onBlur function on EditText in android?

Tags: android

I have a requirement function onBlur like javascript in android. When user exit from an EditText field after typing something in it, then i want to show a Toast. It seems very simple but i could not find it. Any help would highly be appreciated.

Comment: wow....Any help would highly be appreciated? Which way except 1 upvote and answer accept? :D :P lolz

Comment: be Clear! You want onBlur effect or to display toast after onFocus()

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "unfocus", 2000).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Style, it’s a great answer. I have only one EditText field and some TextView and ImageView.  When user switch from  EditText to ImageView then Toast should be appeared.

Comment: You can set a flag in TexEdit onFocus event and get it in ImageView onFocuse event, and then show a Toast message